# Insert multiple objects as instance variable in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Please help me to understand why multiple Objects as instance variable insertion is not woking.

**Professor.java**

```
@Entity
public class Professor {
@Id
private long id;
private String name;
@Embedded
private Courses daycourse;
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="code",column=@Column(name="eve_code")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="desc",column=@Column(name="eve_desc"))})
private Courses evecourse;
// gettter and setters
}
```

**Courses.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class Courses {
private String code;
private String desc;
    // gettter and setters
}
```

**Main.java**

```
         Professor prof = new Professor();
         prof.setId(1);
         prof.setName("leo");

         Courses evecourse = new Courses();
         evecourse.setCode("MCA");
         evecourse.setDesc("Desc");

         Courses daycourse = new Courses();
         daycourse.setCode("MSC");
         daycourse.setDesc("Desc");


         prof.setEvecourse(evecourse);
         prof.setDaycourse(daycourse);



         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
         session.beginTransaction();
         session.save(prof);            
         session.getTransaction().commit();
         session.close();
```

Output :

```
Hibernate: 
    create table Professor (
        id number(19,0) not null,
        code varchar2(255),
        desc varchar2(255),
        eve_code varchar2(255),
        eve_desc varchar2(255),
        name varchar2(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Professor
        (code, desc, eve_code, eve_desc, name, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Jul 05, 2014 12:08:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1747, SQLState: 42000
Jul 05, 2014 12:08:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Jul 05, 2014 12:08:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ORA-01747](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01747.php) error means that you tried to use a column name that is a reserved keyword in Oracle. Look at the list of [Oracle Reserved Words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

The problematic column name here is the `DESC` column. That is a reserved keyword. A simple solution is to also override the attributes for the `daycourse` field:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="code",column=@Column(name="day_code")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="desc",column=@Column(name="day_desc"))})
private Courses daycourse;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="code",column=@Column(name="eve_code")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="desc",column=@Column(name="eve_desc"))})
private Courses evecourse;
```

But the best solution will still be to avoid reserved keywords.

Answer (score 5):

Don't name your column `desc`. It's a reserved SQL keyword (`order by name desc`).

Name it `description`. This won't cause any SQL problem, and it willl make your code and your schema more readable.

Likewise, `Courses` should be named `Course`, `daycourse` should be named `dayCourse`, and `evecourse` should be named `eveningCourse`.